# Make a unique circuit in php tor each user

Tags: php, tor

How can I assign a **unique circuit** to each user in php-tor more correctly? Now I use CURL and in a clever way generate a unique circuit for each user. But is it really unique?

```
$ch = curl_init();   

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'site.onion'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user'.$user_id.':password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

$result = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

Using CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD with different `$user_id` allows you to generate different IP addresses.

How correct is this method to use? The IP does change and it turns out that each user has a unique one, but does the chain itself change? Or are all these IP addresses under the same chain?

I installed tor on the server like this:

```
apt-get install tor
```

Comment: hi, why you want to make unique circuit for each user? how user interact with your script? does it download something for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Tor Browser does to isolate requests for a specific domain to single circuit. Each SOCKS request with the same credentials re-use the same circuit (as long as it's alive) and for new credentials a new circuit is created.

The result is that each request with a different set of credentials uses a different circuit and should have different middle and exit nodes. The guard node is unlikely to change between circuits.

As long as the circuits remain active and functional, requests with those credentials will use the same circuit.

Based on your question, this is the correct method to use and each user will get a unique circuit. Depending on how many you create, there's no guarantee that every single circuit will have a different exit node because exits are limited.

In a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803152/how-can-i-know-the-ip-address-of-tor-route/50863271#50863271) I wrote up some info on how to monitor Tor logs so you can isolate stream events to figure out which circuits they belong to and ultimately what nodes the circuit is built from. You might find that useful for your purposes and if you DM me I can share some unpublished PHP code for doing all of this automatically through the Tor controller.

Comment: If you don't mind, please share the PHP code. I chose Your answer as correct :)

Comment: @ModaL I'll get you that code soon. It relies on a dev version of [torutils](https://github.com/dapphp/torutils) which I need to clean up and release before it is shareable.

Comment: Hi @ModaL Sorry it took longer than expected but I updated the code and created an example that shows how to identify the circuits used by stream-isolated SOCKS client. You can modify it to your needs. The example is [here](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/release-2.0/examples/domaincircuit.php). It uses my torutils library to monitor for STREAM events sent by the Tor controller and match them to requests for specific domains made through curl. Let me know if you have questions about it or want to modify it for a specific purpose. Thanks again for awarding the bounty.